# Bash command doesn't run properly in Python

Tags: python, bash

I have the following files in a directory

```
Co-sqp-C70.pdos_atm*5*C*_wfc*2*p*
Copilot
```

Using `ls Co-sqp*` filters so that the output is

```
Co-sqp-C70.pdos_atm*5*C*_wfc*2*p*
```

However, in a python script, I used

```
cmd = ["ls", self.prefix+".pdos_atm*wfc*"]
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()[0]
print(output)
return output.splitlines()
```

and the output contains both files

```
Co-sqp-C70.pdos_atm*5*C*_wfc*2*p*
Copilot
```

What am I doing wrong in the python code that causes the script to not filter the ls output correctly?

Comment: You have a filename with embedded asterisks?

Comment: Don't use bash (unless you absolutely need to) in Python use Python. Look in to the `os` and `glob` libraries

Comment: @cdarke it's an output file from a program that runs calculations. I have no way of editing the output file name format, so the script is meant to neaten up file names

Comment: Use a string instead of a list for your `cmd`:  `cmd = "ls " + prefix + ".pdos_atm*wfc*"`   (Note the space after the `ls`)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on IanAuld's comment, I would like to offer you two solutions that solve your problem without relying on calling a subprocess. Using subprocesses is kind of clunky and for finding files, python offers several powerful and more pythonic options.

I created a folder named files containing two files with the names you described and a python script in the parent folder:

```
find_files.py
files/
    Co-sqp-C70.pdos_atm*5*C*_wfc*2*p*
    Copilot
```

Now there are several options to do this:

```
import glob
import os

# a glob solution
# you can use wildcards etc like in the command line
print(glob.glob("files/Co-sq*"))

# an os solution
# you can walk through all files and only print/ keep those that start with your desired string
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("files/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith("Co-sq"):
            print(file)
```

I would prefer the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) solution for finding files, because it is quite flexible and easy to use. As the name suggests, glob allows you to use [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) as you know them from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your command isn't `bash` it's `ls`.  There's no shell involved to expand your filename pattern `self.prefix+".pdos_atm*wfc*"`, so `ls` gets that as a literal argument, as if you'd entered (in a shell)

```sh
ls 'Co-sqp-C70.pdos_atm*wfc*'
```

You have at least these options:

1. Invoke a shell to expand the pattern:

   ```
   cmd = [ "sh", "-c", "ls " + self.prefix + ".pdos_atm*wfc*"]
   ```

   Equivalently:

   ```
   cmd = "ls " + self.prefix + ".pdos_atm*wfc*"
   ```

   This is risky if `self.prefix` isn't guaranteed to be shell-clean.
2. Expand the glob, and pass the results to `ls`:

   ```
   import glob
   cmd = ["ls"] + glob.glob(self.prefix+".pdos_atm*wfc*")
   ```

   You're still using `ls`, which is not intended to give parseable output.  Don't do any more than simply passing the output to a user (e.g. in a log file).
3. Expand the glob, and process the results in python:

   ```
   import glob
   for file in glob.glob(self.prefix+".pdos_atm*wfc*"):
       some_function(file)
   ```

   You should do this if you want to examine the file entries in any way.